# Testing multiple XCTests

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest

I have multiple Xcode projects inside a workspace. Each project consists of static library target and test target. All test targets perform when I select single project.

Question: It is possible to create a single project, that runs all the tests in other projects?

Comment: You should be able to set that up in the scheme `Product > Edit Scheme > Test` then check which target testing you want to run when you run tests.

Comment: @sbarow exactly what I needed